# How can I edit a draft version of an article with apex?

Tags: lookup, knowledge, articles

```
trigger CloseArticleFeedback on aft__Article_Feedback__c (before update, before insert) {

for (aft__Article_Feedback__c f : trigger.new) {

    if (f.aft__Feedback_Status__c == 'Closed') { 

        //Retrieve Specific ArticleTypeVersion
        String r = 'select articleNumber, Id, Article_Template__c, Feedback_In_Progress__c from Technical_Article__kav where PublishStatus = \'draft\' and Language = \'en_US\'';
        r += 'and articleNumber = \''+ f.aft__Article_Number__c +'\' limit 1';

        Technical_Article__kav at_kav = (Technical_Article__kav) Database.query(r); 

        at_kav.Feedback_In_Progress__c = NULL;
        update at_kav;

}}

}
```

I have a custom field on articles that is a lookup to the Article Feedback custom object. When an article feedback record is closed I would like to remove the relationship from the draft version of the article.

I feel like the code above is close, but obviously its not working. Any ideas?

Comment: So I figured it out. I needed to add "update at_kav;" in order to save the changes I made to the draft article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. I needed to add "update at_kav;" in order to save the changes I made to the draft article.